# Random string not in DB

Tags: php, function, random, mysqli

Newish to PHP/MySQL, I have been trying to copy the check random string from a few of the other posts and have not had much luck any input would be helpful.

The goal to make a random 8 digit pin that is not in the DB.

```
    function generateQuickPin($length = 8) {

    define ("DB_HOST", "localhost"); //Databse Host.
    define ("DB_USER", "6eef"); //Databse User.
    define ("DB_PASS", "a0b1"); //database password.
    define ("DB_NAME", "timecard"); //database Name.

    $db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    $flength = 1;
    $characters = '123456789';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randompin = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $flength; $i++) {
        $randompin .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }

    $length = $length - 1;
    $characters = '0123456789';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randompin .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `quick_pin` = '$randompin' ";
    if ($db->query($query) === TRUE) {

        }else {
        $randomString = 'false '.$db->error;
        return $randomString;
    }
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ # in case a record with this "text" already exists, run this method again
        generateQuickPin(8);
    } else {
        return $randomString; # otherwise return the value/store it in the object
    }

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Do you declare $result anywhere?
If not, Replace:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
```

with

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($db->query($query)) > 0)
```

Comment: The issue seems to be around line 26 at the IF statement where if it fails it should return false with the error, but it's only returning the false and nothing else....

Comment: where do you define result? I am pretty sure $db->query() returns a result so instead of using: $db->query($query)===TRUE, use $db->query($query)!==false

Comment: The last if statement says if found go again else return randompin (already fixed that miss type if the past if)

Comment: Is it supposed to be returning an error? Because if not, try changing what the answer says to change.

Comment: The second to last if statement is a check the db or error out. if error echo false + db error but it only returned false with no pin or error

Comment: This is because there is **no** error in the first place. You are checking to see if $db->query($query) returns true, $db->($query) will never return true, It will either return false or a mysqli_result object. So you must change `$db->query($query)===TRUE` to `$db->query($query)!==false`